# catch exception when uploading excel document fails

Tags: c#, .net, exception

maybe someone can help me with the following problem. The default.aspx page in my webapplication contains a upload control. The user is able to upload records from a excel document. But if it throws a exception, i want to recieve the record row number and show it in a message box ( see below):

```
if (FileUpload.HasFile)
{

    string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + FileUpload.FileName));
    FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
    string constr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);

    ITransaction trans = Data.Instance.NHibernateSession.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet$]", conn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Relation relation = new Relatie();

                    relation.name = reader[0].ToString();
                    relation.function = reader[1].ToString();
                   relation.Email = reader[2].ToString();


                }

            }

            trans.Commit();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        trans.Rollback();

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Upload document failed: ROW NUMBER..????????:" + ex.Message);



    }
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to show a Windows Form message box in a n asp.net application ???

Comment: Make an int counter variable in the while loop... btw, what kind of exception do you get?

Comment: it catchs  sql exception if the record contains to many characters in the name' field (for example)

Comment: Are you saving the `relation` to DB?

Comment: yes i am uploading the records to the relation table

Comment: So you need to get the error if some exception gets in uploading a row? But you are commiting to the DB after adding all rows. So if an exception occurs, you will rollback all the rows. Correct?

Comment: yes. the row number in a alertbox should conform.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add row by row to DB, instead of single commit.Now just move the try catch block where you are saving the row to DB

```
if (FileUpload.HasFile)
{

string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + FileUpload.FileName));
FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
string constr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);

ITransaction trans = Data.Instance.NHibernateSession.BeginTransaction();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet$]", conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Relation relation = new Relatie();
                try
                {


                  relation.name = reader[0].ToString();
                  relation.function = reader[1].ToString();
                  relation.Email = reader[2].ToString();

                  // Save to DB
               }
               catch(SqlException ex)
               {
                  // Get the data from relation object
               }
            }
        }

        trans.Commit();
    }
     File.Delete(path);
}
```

Comment: this gives some serious perforamce problems. Im uploading large excel documents

Comment: But you need to report each row which is causing some error

Comment: yes, with the amount of records in the excel file, this isnt gonna work. I should look for another solution.

Comment: @user3114347 are you looking for record number of the very first row which is erroneous or you want to create a list of all the erroneous rows in the excel? Also in case of error do you want to commit the good rows into DB or you would want to rollback them as well?